# What is best practice for saving code changes of task #1 (pending code review) before conducting the code changes for task #2

Tags: git

Assume the following:

- A software development team which works with Git. Each developer has its own local repository.
- Code review -> staging -> committing -> pushing code changes into remote repository.

I wonder what is the best practice for the following popular scenario:

- Developer did all the necessary code changes for task #1.
- Developer starts task #2 which requires additional code changes.

IMO, I guess it's correct to keep the working directory only with one set of file changes (related to the same task) so we won't mix too much code in working directory.

My question is how to store the changes related to task #1 so we can continue with a clean working directory before starting task #2?

**Approach #1**
Stash task #1 code changes -> work on task #2 -> task #2 related code review -> apply code review comments -> stage, commit and push task #2 code changes -> "git stash apply" and then repeating the same flow...

**Approach #2**
Commit task #1 file changes (before code review) -> task #1 code review -> do extra commit applying the code review comments -> then push to remote branch -> starting task #2

**Approach #3**
Create a branch just for working on the #2 task.

If you find the best approach not one of the above, please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: How do you do the code review? Just sharing diffs? It seems natural to commit (either locally or remotely but on a different branch) before doing the code review.

Comment: "Code review -> staging -> committing -> pushing code changes into remote repository" ... you do realize using that sequence is tantamount to refusing to use git at  all, right?  What goes on in a developer's repo is their own business, you've got no more reason to examine that than the notes on their desk or the thoughts in their head.  If you're going to mandate code review, have a code-review repo devs push to and whoever gets it after review pulls from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each task should have it's own branch in the local repository.  If task #2 depends on the changes made in task #1, then it should branch off the HEAD of the branch for task #1 (rather than, e.g, `master`).

Developers should regularly update their local `master` branch and rebase any work in progress on top of those changes.  Similarly, if changes are necessary to the code for task #1, then the task #2 branch should be rebased on top of those changes.

This ensure that there is a clear change history for each task, and that the changes for each task will merge cleanly into `master` (or other upstream branch) when they are reviewed.